# useEffect needs to call function and render it after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to show cookies after 5 seconds on the home pages. The function renderCookie works fine but I'm not sure how to implement useUffect and to call function renderCookie after 5 seconds. At the moment it runs immediately but not after 5 seconds. Anyone have any suggestions, I'm not sure where I went wrong?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { MdDone } from "react-icons/md";
import {getCookie, setCookie} from 'tiny-cookie';

const CookieNotice = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState({
        name: "zureaCookie",
        value: ""
    });

useEffect(() => {
    const delay = 5000; 
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        renderCookie();
        
    }, delay);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, []);


    const acceptCookie = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newItemsObj = {...items};
        newItemsObj.value = "Accepted";
        setItems(newItemsObj);
        setCookie(items.name, newItemsObj.value, { expires: '1Y' });
    }

    const declineCookie = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newItemsObj = {...items};
        newItemsObj.value = "Declined";
        setItems(newItemsObj);
        setCookie(items.name, newItemsObj.value, { expires: '1Y' });
    }

        const renderCookie = () => {
            const zureaCookie = getCookie(items.name);
            return (
                <>
                    {!zureaCookie ? (<div className="cookie-notice-container">
                        <div className="cookie-notice-wrapper">
                            <div className="cookie-notice-content">
                                <p>We use cookies to improve your experience on our website. By browsing this website,
                                    you agree to our use of cookies.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="cookie-notice-btn-wrapper">
                                <a href="" className="btn-terms">Terms & Conditions</a>
                                <a href="" className="btn-decline" onClick={declineCookie}>Decline</a>
                                <a href="" className="btn-accept" onClick={acceptCookie}>Accept<MdDone className="md-done" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>) : (null)}
                </>);
           
        }

        
    return renderCookie();

}

export default CookieNotice;
```

Comment: you can set a new state that indicates 5 seconds are passed or not. And based on that state, you can return renderCookie() result or return nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { MdDone } from "react-icons/md";
import { getCookie, setCookie } from "tiny-cookie";

const CookieNotice = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState({
    name: "zureaCookie",
    value: "",
  });
  const [elapsed, setElapsed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const delay = 5000;
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setElapsed(true);
    }, delay);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, []);

  const acceptCookie = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newItemsObj = { ...items };
    newItemsObj.value = "Accepted";
    setItems(newItemsObj);
    setCookie(items.name, newItemsObj.value, { expires: "1Y" });
  };

  const declineCookie = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newItemsObj = { ...items };
    newItemsObj.value = "Declined";
    setItems(newItemsObj);
    setCookie(items.name, newItemsObj.value, { expires: "1Y" });
  };

  const renderCookie = () => {
    const zureaCookie = getCookie(items.name);
    return (
      <>
        {!zureaCookie && elapsed ? (
          <div className="cookie-notice-container">
            <div className="cookie-notice-wrapper">
              <div className="cookie-notice-content">
                <p>
                  We use cookies to improve your experience on our website. By browsing this website, you agree to our
                  use of cookies.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="cookie-notice-btn-wrapper">
                <a href="" className="btn-terms">
                  Terms & Conditions
                </a>
                <a href="" className="btn-decline" onClick={declineCookie}>
                  Decline
                </a>
                <a href="" className="btn-accept" onClick={acceptCookie}>
                  Accept
                  <MdDone className="md-done" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </>
    );
  };

  return renderCookie();
};

export default CookieNotice;
```